# Can you set a cell to have a price on it linked to the main website?

Tags: google-sheets

I work in the parts department of an auto-repair shop and have been charged with organizing everything and creating an inventory sheet.

I have done all of that and am now trying to improve the system for future use. So I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to link the prices for the parts that I have in my Sheet to the website where we get our parts from so the prices are always updated, and so I don't have to forever look them up on the main website to double check that my prices are outdated.

So overall I'm trying to take a small but specific amount of information from a website and put it on my Sheet so it can be viewed there but will update along with the original website.

I may not have explained that in the best way, feel free to ask questions.

Comment: Welcome. IMHO the question is too broad for this this site. Please add more details to make it specific and add a brief description of your search/research efforts. Ref. [ask].

Comment: Well the answer seems to have answered my question fairly well, what I'm looking to do won't work with this particular website.

Comment: If you are satisfied with the referred answer, say thank you to the author by accepting it and/or answering some of their answers. Ref. [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Oh, we're still discussing things, but my initial question has been solved. I'm sorry, I don't know the protocol here, but I will be sure to mark this as solved once the discussion is finished and there are no more ideas left for me to try. Feel free to look at the other comments to see if you are able to help some more. I would appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: If looks that you are talking about a followup question which is pretty fine, but that followup question should be posted as new question instead of "perpetually" discussing it on an post that already answer the initial question.

Comment: Good call. I'll do that now.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need to lookup for formula from **`IMPORT`** family:

- **`=IMPORTRANGE()`**
- **`=IMPORTDATA()`**
- **`=IMPORTHTML()`**
- **`=IMPORTFEED()`**
- **`=IMPORTXML()`**

**EXAMPLE:**

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZQHZho8A-Ew"; 
           "//div[@class='watch-view-count']")
```

This formula will return the number of views of a particular video.

**NOTE:** There are certain limitations which may cause that **`IMPORT`** function won't work:

---

[image]

---

Comment: okay it would be one webpage for each item, but this would be an example page:https://www.nivelparts.com/product/5029/lug-nut-1-2-20-cce-bag-20

Comment: @thefirstwaldo it seems that this cant be done for this particular site, because the price is an output of javascript not standalone piece of information in source code. are there any other options? maybe some other site which is scraping prices from this site?

Comment: I'll look around and see what I can find, but I doubt any others will have all the information I'm looking for.

Comment: also you could try to reach administrator/creator of that website and ask for raw data and import it from there before it gets javascripted

Comment: Checked my other sites, and the prices are either different or the parts aren't there. 

I'll see if I can reach out to the administrator of the site. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I just noticed the screenshot of the coding above. Is there any way to reference the code directly? Or would it still not work because of the javascript? I don't really know how this all works, and just I'm trying to be thorough

Comment: @thefirstwaldo you can get it with: `=IMPORTXML("https://www.nivelparts.com/product/5029/lug-nut-1-2-20-cce-bag-20","//*")` but that wont help you I guess

Comment: Contacted the company and they notified me that they do not allow the site to be "scrapped for pricing" because of past impacts on the performance of the site. They have given me access to a pdf file that I would have to redownload every time there was a price change. So now, my question has changed a bit, can I reference a pdf file the same way I can reference a website?

Comment: @thefirstwaldo https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers